# sqlalchemy multiple flush before commit

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want insert records to 3 tables. The codes is below.

```
    sessionDB.autocommit = False
    # insert Address
    addrRecord = Addres(street=street, city=city, zip_code=zip_code)
    sessionDB.add(addrRecord)
    sessionDB.flush()

    # insert customer
    cRecord = Customer(email=email, passwords=password, kind='individual', aID=addrRecord.aID)
    sessionDB.add(cRecord)
    sessionDB.flush()

    # insert Hcustomer
    homeCRecord = HomeCu(cID=cRecord.cID, fname=first_name, lname=last_name, age=age, marriage=marriage, remain=remain)
    sessionDB.add(homeCRecord)

    print (addrRecord.city, cRecord.kind, homeCRecord.lname)
    sessionDB.commit()
```

The Addres's key is aID and Customer's key is cID. They are auto increment. In Customer, there is a foreign key constrained by Addres's aID. HomeCu's foreign key cID is constrained by Customer's cID.
So I want to insert Addres, Customer, HomeCu sequentially, during which I have to get the keys without doing commit. I used flush() to get the keys but failed at commit operation. Why during the commit operation, the value like email, password become None, but the print sentence is doing well? I have been struggling on this for hours. You help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!!!

Here is the error log:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 1193, in _execute_context    context)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py",
>   line 509, in do_execute    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py",
>   line 170, in execute    result = self._query(query)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py",
>   line 328, in _query    conn.query(q)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
>   line 516, in query    self._affected_rows =
>   self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
>   line 727, in _read_query_result    result.read()
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
>   line 1066, in read    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
>   line 683, in _read_packet    packet.check_error()
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py",
>   line 220, in check_error    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/err.py",
>   line 109, in raise_mysql_exception    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
>   pymysql.err.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'email' cannot be null")
>          The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>          Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Volumes/Code/Previous
>   Content/grad/2018_2019/db/final/app/modelController.py", line 164, in 
>       registerIndividual('534 Tilling St', 'New York', '15233',
>   '123@qq.com', '123', 'Zimo', 'Tang', 23, 755.23, 0)
>   File
>   "/Volumes/Code/Previous
>   Content/grad/2018_2019/db/final/app/modelController.py", line 129, in 
>   registerIndividual    sessionDB.commit()
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 943, in commit    self.transaction.commit()
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 467, in commit    self._prepare_impl()
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 447, in _prepare_impl    self.session.flush()
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 2254, in flush    self._flush(objects)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 2381, in _flush    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py",
>   line 66, in **exit**    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
>   line 249, in reraise    raise value
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
>   line 2345, in _flush    flush_context.execute()
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py",
>   line 395, in execute    rec.execute(self)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py",
>   line 560, in execute    uow
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py",
>   line 181, in save_obj    mapper, table, insert)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py",
>   line 830, in _emit_insert_statements    execute(statement,
>   multiparams)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 948, in execute    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py",
>   line 269, in _execute_on_connection    return
>   connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 1060, in _execute_clauseelement    compiled_sql, distilled_params
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 1200, in _execute_context    context)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 1413, in _handle_dbapi_exception    exc_info
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
>   line 265, in raise_from_cause    reraise(type(exception), exception,
>   tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py",
>   line 248, in reraise    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
>   line 1193, in _execute_context    context)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py",
>   line 509, in do_execute    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py",
>   line 170, in execute    result = self._query(query)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py",
>   line 328, in _query    conn.query(q)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
>   line 516, in query    self._affected_rows =
>   self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
>   line 727, in _read_query_result    result.read()
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
>   line 1066, in read    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py",
>   line 683, in _read_packet    packet.check_error()
>   File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py",
>   line 220, in check_error    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/err.py",
>   line 109, in raise_mysql_exception    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
>   sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1048,
>   "Column 'email' cannot be null")    [SQL: 'INSERT INTO customer
>   (`cID`, email, passwords, kind, `aID`)    VALUES (%(cID)s, %(email)s,
>   %(passwords)s, %(kind)s, %(aID)s)']    [parameters: {'cID': 31,
>   'email': None, 'passwords': None, 'kind':    None, 'aID': None}]
>   (Background on this error at:    http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: You go to great lengths to describe your models and constraints but the best thing you could do is include a [minimal version of them that allows us to easily reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: is this issue is solved as i am facing the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
addrRecord = sessionDB.query(Addres).filter(Addres.street == street).filter(Addres.city == city) \
                .filter(Addres.zip_code == zip_code).first()
            cRecord = Customer(email=email, passwords=password, kind='individual', aID=addrRecord.aID)
            homeCRecord = HomeCu(fname=first_name, lname=last_name, age=age, marriage=marriage, remain=remain)
            homeCRecord.customer = cRecord
            sessionDB.add(cRecord)
            sessionDB.add(homeCRecord)
```

I didn' t use flush finally. I think using flush for multiple time will cause error. I add the relationship in instance. Hope this can help someone.